# Calling LinEst and INDEX Fuctions

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a module that makes a simple linear regression many times over many different data ranges. For this i am using a loop where i use the `LinEst` function inside `INDEX` function so that i can extract the slope and the intercept.
The problem i am having is that at the line 9 the program crashes sending me an

> error(5): "Invalid argument or procedure call".

**Edited: Corrections Made.**

**Now at line 11 it says:**

> error(1004): "can not read the LinEst property of the worksheet function class".

**Update: it's working fine now i just deleted the word WorksheetFunction**

```
Sub regression()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim range1 As Range
    Dim range2 As Range
    
    j = 139
    i = 4
    For i = 4 To 54 Step 1
    
     Set range2 = Range(Sheets(1).Cells(22, j), Sheets(1).Cells(66, j))
     Set range1 = Range(Sheets(1).Cells(22, j - 1), Sheets(1).Cells(66, j - 1))
      
    Sheets(12).Cells(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(range1, range2), 1)
    Sheets(12).Cells(i, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(range1, range2), 2)

      j = j - 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that if you `Dim i, j as Integer` that only `j` is an `Integer`. You need `Dim i as Integer, j as Integer`. Same goes for `range1` and `range2`. Also, if they're `Range`s, you need to use `Set`: `Set range2 = ...` and `Set range1 =...`

Comment: I don't get as far as line 9.  Your code stops at line 7 with `run-time error 91`

Comment: After i made the corrections Now at line 11 it says:

 > error(1004): "can not read the LinEst property of the worksheet function class".

Comment: it's working fine now i just deleted the word WorksheetFunction

Comment: Just want to caution everybody that the error 1004 Unable to get the LinEst property of the WorksheetFunction class can also occur if any of your arrays contains undetermined values, like the error you get from trying to calculate the Ln of cero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for the [`Range` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.range).

If you want to refer to a range from `Cells(22, j)` to `Cells(66, j)`, and both those cells are on `Sheets(1)`, then **instead of** :

```
range2 = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(22, j), Cells(66, j))
```

you'd use:

```
range2 = Range(Sheets(1).Cells(22, j), Sheets(1).Cells(66, j))
```

or:

```
With Sheets(1)
    range2 = Range(.Cells(22, j),.Cells(66, j))
End With
```

In this case the first loop would assign `range2` an object representing `$EI$22:$EI$66`.

The following line has the same issue.

Comment: After i made the corrections Now at line 11 it says: > error(1004): "can not read the LinEst property of the worksheet function class".

Comment: it's working fine now i just deleted the word WorksheetFunction